# The King gave it to the Queen, but the Queen found nothing

Tags: lateral-thinking

This was a riddle which was puzzling me in childhood.

> King gave the 'Thing' in Queen's hand, and Queen saw that in light of
>   burning lamp... Hush, Queen sees nothing.

What is the 'Thing'?

Comment: the 'Thing' is a physical quantity or not? or something like `shake hand` ?

Comment: Yeah..It's **physical** quantity

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is it

> An Ice Cube

Explanation

> the ice cube might have melted down by the time the queen reached near the light.

Comment: Yeah..you are right...!!!

Comment: I need to know, Why would a king give his queen that?

Comment: There are things two consenting adults can do with an ice cube.

Comment: I'm not sure is it the case, ice melts not evaporate. Hence queen should see water not nothing.

Comment: The queen was a fatty and the skin absorbed all of the water

Answer (score 20):

It might be

> [**Dimethyl Cadmium**](http://blogs.sciencemag.org/pipeline/archives/2013/05/08/things_i_wont_work_with_dimethylcadmium) because it is very reactive. It will burn Queen's hand and then its gaseous molecules will kill the Queen. So she sees nothing.

Comment: Dark and quite lateral thinking. I like the cut of your jib, sir.

Answer (score 2):

I think it might be

> Mercury, after king give it to her, and she got poisoned. As mercury poisoning causes vision problems, queen couldn't see nothing.

Answer (score 1):

How about

> The Queen is **blind**. Therefore, she always sees nothing.
> She can check any physical item the King can give to her by using the other senses.
>
> As for the "in light of the burning lamp", it's because the royal couple is either **outside**, or **near a fire**, which makes them in light of the burning (and lightening) sun or fire in all circumstances.

Comment: We can say that Queen can **SEE** as she goes near light and try to figure out what king gave her.

Comment: @hvd I have to point out that the word "seen" in the original version was changed in Revision 3 (not by OP) to become "checked". Oh well...

Comment: @Anton Oh! Thanks for pointing that out. That is a very bad edit, that removes essential information from the riddle.

Answer (score 1):

Kinda funny but still possibility.

> flash bomb - After blast she sees nothing but the white light.